# Unable to click on next button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I've been at this for hours and haven't made any progress. I'm trying to click on the next button on this page [here](https://www.govinfo.gov/app/collection/uscourts/district/alsd/2021/%7B%22pageSize%22%3A%22500%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%220%22%7D)

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin python3

import sys
import time
import re
import logging
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


_USE_VIRTUAL_DISPLAY = False
_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s'
# logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(format=_FORMAT, level=logging.INFO)
_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(sys.argv[0])
_DEFAULT_SLEEP = 0.5


try:
    options = options()
    # options.headless = True
    

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r"/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
    
    print("Started Browser and Driver")


except:
    _LOGGER.info("Can not run headless mode.")

url = 'https://www.govinfo.gov/app/collection/uscourts/district/alsd/2021/%7B%22pageSize%22%3A%22100%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%220%22%7D'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

page = driver.page_source
soup = bs(page, "html.parser")


next_page = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="collapseOne1690"]/div/span[1]/div/ul/li[8]/a')))
if next_page:
    print('*****getting next page*****')
    # driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', next_page)
    next_page.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    
else:
    print('no next page')
    

driver.quit()
```

I get a timeout error.  I've tried changing the XPath. I've tried ActionChains to scroll into view and none have worked. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Your XPATH does not work because it uses dynamic class name `collapseOne1690`, as was mentioned earlier.
Also, it's not very stable even if you used a part of this class name.
If you prefer XPaths, I'd suggest this one: `//span[@class='custom-paginator']//li[@class='next fw-pagination-btn']/a` or just `//li[@class='next fw-pagination-btn']/a`. You can also use css selector: `.next.fw-pagination-btn`

2 I got rid of logging code because it also has some issues, re-check it.

3  5 seconds explicit wait is too small. Make it at least 10 seconds, better 15. It's just a suggestion.

The smallest reproducible code which clicks the button and uses Firefox is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = options()
# options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

print("Started Browser and Driver")

url = 'https://www.govinfo.gov/app/collection/uscourts/district/alsd/2021/%7B%22pageSize%22%3A%22100%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%220%22%7D'

driver.get(url)

page = driver.page_source
soup = bs(page, "html.parser")
print(soup)

next_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='custom-paginator']//li[@class='next fw-pagination-btn']/a")))
next_page.click()

# driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears when I load up this page that the div id's are assigned dynamically. The first time I loaded the page, the id was `collapseOne5168`, the second time it was `collapseOne1136`

You might consider using `find_element_by_class_name("next fw-pagination-btn")` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That got the old "unable to locate element" error.  This is a tough one

Comment: `find_element_by_class_name` works only when a single class name is passed.